# Multiple OpenGL contexts / views

Tags: opengl

I'm supposed to write an OpenGL program, which displays a 3D view of an object, two views each showing a cross sections of the 3D object and one view showing the a scan signal of the object. All this resides in one Windows window (dialog window). The contents of the four views by definition are related to each other but I have somehow difficulties to figure out how to implement the four views from the OpenGL point of view.

- is it the multiple OpenGL contexts or multiple viewports solution I should go for?
- how would the shader programs be linked to each individual context or viewport? Would there be separate shader programs for each view?

Comment: I haven't done this, but I believe you use `glViewport` to restrict the canvas to a portion of the window, then render normally; repeat for each view.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already found out, you have basically two options how to show a model from different viewpoints. Which one to choose depends on what you need, since both have some advantages and some drawbacks.

**Solution 1: One Context**

In this case, you specify the area in which you want to render each view by using glViewport and then render normally. In this case, you need the data and shaders only once, since you are rendering in the same context. The drawback of this method is, that all views together have to span a rectangular area, without any other controls located between them. In addition it is not possible to have different views rendered in different windows.

**Solution 2: Multiple Viewports**

Here, you have a window handle (and a context) for each view separately. In this case, there are no limitations regarding the arrangement of different views, but you have to have the data and shaders loaded multiple times (one time in each context). Depending on which system you are working on, there might be some options to share OpenGL objects between different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this multiple ways even with a single OpenGL context. Some of the obvious options are:

- Use `glViewport` - this function defines where OpenGL will draw on the window (a rectangle in pixels). Call it once for 3D view (probably something like `glViewport(0, 0, window_width / 2, window_height / 2)`), render the 3D view, call for first cross section, render it, and so on.
- Use offscreen rendering - create a framebuffer, render to specified corners of the framebuffer (which can be considered to be a virtual screen), and draw the final texture from the framebuffer on the window.